# How to get the data including the relation table's entry with a GET request in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying my hand at DRF recently and I've got this issue below to be solved for my project.

I've two **Models**

```
class JobsMaster(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    scheduled_time = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    args = models.TextField()
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    repeat = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class JobProcessDetails(models.Model):
    job_id = models.ForeignKey('JobsMaster')
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    step_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    records = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=155,default='system')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('job_id', 'sequence'),)
```

Corresponding **Serializers**

```
class JobsMasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = JobsMaster
        fields = '__all__'

class JobProcessDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = JobProcessDetails
        fields = '__all__'
```

their **Viewsets**

```
class JobsMasterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = JobsMaster.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobsMasterSerializer
    filter_fields = ('job_id',)

class JobProcessDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = JobProcessDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobProcessDetailsSerializer
    filter_fields = ('job_id','sequence',)
```

I do not know if this is the right way to build viewsets and serializer but it worked for me.

I want to write a GET request from UI to fetch the data from `JobProcessDetails` which includes the data from the related `JobsMaster` table as well.

for example, the response data should be containing the below fields

```
    job_id : xxxxx
    sequence : xxxx
    step_name : 'xxxx'
    records : xxxx
    created_by : 'xxxxx'
    created_on : dd/mm/yyyy
    job_id__job_name : 'xxxxx'
    job_id__scheduled_time : 'xxxxx'
    job_id__args : 'xxxxx'
    job_id__interval : 'xxxxx'
    job_id__repeat : 'xxxxx'
```

Is there any way that I can tweak something to get this with a single GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
class JobProcessDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  job_id = JobsMasterSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = JobProcessDetails
    fields = [
      'job_id '
      'sequence'
      'step_name'
      'records'
      'created_by' 
      'created_on'
    ]
```